# XAMPP / Textmate problem with OSX Lion?

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, terminal, xampp

i just upgraded to Lion and i am trying to set the .bash_profile file for XAMPP but i keep getting:

mate .bash_profile
-bash: mate: command not found

mysql
-bash: mysql: command not found

can someone please tell me what i need to do as i cant even open the hidden .bash_profile without textmate (mate)?

Thank you in advance ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you can do 3 things,

In textmate you can do the "open" and in the dialog, a checkbox in the botom "Show hidden files" will let you open the .bash_profile

Or you can go to textmate -> help > terminal usage , and there install the mate helper

Or you can use the "pico" editor in the terminal (it's command line editor, but it's simple)